# Can DataPower Operations Dashboard version 10.0.13 (DPOD) be upgraded and which one is the support lifecycle?

Tags: version-control, websphere, ibm-datapower

Can DataPower Operations Dashboard version 10.0.13 (DPOD) be upgraded? and  **Which one is the support lifecycle or end of support for this version?**
The IBM support by clarity says that my DPOD version is the last one, but I would like to have a second validation.

https://www.ibm.com/support/lifecycle/search?q=datapower%20operations%20dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You're right !!
IBM DataPower Gateways 10.0.x is the latest one and DataPower Operations Dashboard v1.0.13.0 is the latest. There is no end of support determined yet for this version.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to check the status for you !! Hope it answered your question.